# Can you create Build and Release Definitions for Website projects not Web Applications in TFS2015?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, tfs-2015, build-definition

Is this possible?

We currently have build definitions and release definitions setup and working for Web Applications.  However we have a lot of older web site type projects and will not work with the current build and release definitions that we already have setup.

Is there a way for us to get the web site projects to work with the build and release definitions in TFS?

Thanks

Recently changed my steps for the build definition and now that build is successful but the release still fails.

Build definition Steps are:
Nuget Installer, Copy Files, and Copy and Publish Build Artifacts

Release definition Steps are:
Powershell on Target Machines, and Windows Machine Files Copy

Comment: I've tested a WebSite project in TFS 2015 with Build and Release definitions, but didn't get any error. Could you specify why do you can't create Build and Release Definitions for Website projects? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I get a (ASPNETCOMPILER (0, 0) "directory doesn't exist" error) and (Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.)

Comment: Will you also get this error if you create a new website project and queue build and release? How's your build and release definition like? Please share it in the original post.

Comment: Added what you asked for

Comment: What error do you get in release?

Comment: 2017-01-17T18:28:09.8846757Z ##[error]The item drop in container 24597 could not be found.

Comment: Could you post the entire release log in the original post? Have you checked your drop location to see whether it is empty? How did you link your build artifacts to your release?

Answer (score 0):

As web site projects needs bin folder and TFS doesn't want them to be stored in source, the best way to achieve is to convert web site projects to web application.

Best practice: Converting to web application:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx

But they made a workaround maybe you can try:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/09/21/building-a-website-with-tfs-build/